# 2 same codes in PHP, one is wrong

Tags: php

```
// Not working
$stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO numbers (homePhone, mobilePhone, officePhone)".
    " VALUES ($phone_1,$phone_2,$phone_3)");
$stmt->execute();

// Works
$stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO numbers (homePhone, mobilePhone, officePhone)".
    " VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute([$phone_1, $phone_2, $phone_3]);
```

When the first one is executed, it prints the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1
>   no such column: blablabla in
>   C:\Users\zahha\IdeaProjects\icd0007\index.php:78 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Users\zahha\IdeaProjects\icd0007\index.php(78):
>   PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO peo...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\zahha\IdeaProjects\icd0007\index.php on line 78

The second one works perfectly. What is the problem? Just wondering.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make the first one work, you should put the variables between '. For example:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO numbers (homePhone, mobilePhone, officePhone)".
    " VALUES ('$phone_1','$phone_2','$phone_3')");
$stmt->execute();
```

Or taking them out of the string, like:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO numbers (homePhone, mobilePhone, officePhone)".
    " VALUES ('".$phone_1."','".$phone_2."','".$phone_3."')");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Taking them out of the string doesn't solve it, you still need quotes around them.

Comment: True. I will edit my answer

Comment: @maksim make sure you understand the concept of SQL injection and why parametrization / binding is desirable.

Comment: It's not in the scope of the question, but seeing how easily you can mess things up by not parameterizing, you might as well just do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the variables in the first one, to indicate that the values are string literals in SQL.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO numbers (homePhone, mobilePhone, officePhone)".
    " VALUES ('$phone_1','$phone_2','$phone_3')");
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote here.